# What kind of date stamp is this?

Tags: binary-format

I'm looking at the OLK files created by Outlook for Mac, and these appear to be the date fields, but I cannot figure out what kind of binary dates they are.

There are 2 values in one file (reversed from LE):

```
DATE1: 41 C0 A0 72 E7 F5 F6 A9
DATE2: 41 C0 A0 72 E9 2B 82 BA
```

One of these apparently decodes to Thu, 06 Sep 2018 00:34:23 -0400, but I can't figure out how.

These don't appear to be any of the Windows FileTime or OLE formats, and it isn't any of the Mac formats that I've seen before.

Here's another example:

```
41 BB 67 A9 0A 00 00 00 --> 7/28/2015 12:11:54 UTC
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a 64 bit floating point value.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate

Returns a `TimeInterval` which happens to be `typealias TimeInterval = Double`

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval

As in the source above, the epoch here is seconds from Jan 1 2001. But it's stored as a float.

---

`41 BB 67 A9 0A 00 00 00` is about `459778314` seconds which is `Jul 28 2015, 12:11:54 PM`

`41 C0 A0 72 E7 F5 F6 A9` is about `557901263` which is `Sep 6 2018, 6:34:23 AM UTC`

`41 C0 A0 72 E9 2B 82 BA` is about `557901266` which is `Sep 6 2018, 6:34:26 AM UTC`

Comment: I also thought it would be a double, but expected it to be the [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day). Well done!